# TYPO3: General Storage Folder not working

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

In my plugin, I can't set the General Storage Folder. I changed it in the plugin settings itself and in the page settings. Still, creating elements in the Frontend with the plugin stores them inside the page:id=0.

Does anyone have a quick solution?

Comment: Can you post related code/setting there, so we can help you?

Comment: @Alex thats the problem: i don't know where this related code would be

Comment: We need the TCA of the table (ctrl section and the column effected) and the flexform settings of the plugin (if any).

Comment: @pgampe I don't even know where to find these flexform settings, so I may assume that I haven't edited them either. Plus, inside the TCA I searched via `Cmd + F` for "stor" without any result. I just found out that another extension uses the page:uid=0 as storage folder regardless of the storage folder which is set inside the plugins settings. May there be a connection?

Comment: Plugin settings come from flexform. I usually just set the pid explicitly inside a plugin. I do not know to what extend extbase supports general record storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `storagePid` can be configured in multiple places.
One is inside the plugin record in field "*Record Storage Page*". You can also define recursion.

[image]

Another place is TypoScript with option `persistence.storagePid` that is documented at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html#persistence

There, you can also configure the `newRecordStoragePid`:

> Page-ID in which new records of the given class should be saved.

And there is Flexform, if you provide it and provide a way to set the TypoScript setting, but that invokes some steps on your side and as you didn't do anything that will not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the problem somehow solved itself. Just created a new ext with the extension builder from scratch and it worked. Don't ask me how. Actually, I started developing the ext on another domain because I got fed up with that and after importing to the old domain  it displayed the records - You'll still get the green hook because I'm supporting people who are willing to do some extra work in order to help people. Thanks.

Comment: If you want the setting from "Record Storage Page" in the backend to work, you need to disable the default storage pid in `setup.txt` using `plugin.tx_your_ext.persistence.storagePid >` and remove the setting from `constants.txt`.